# Como checar em uma diretiva Angular se o node pai é um link?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directives

Preciso fazer uma verificação se minha diretiva `xx-chip` está dentro de um link. Não posso utilizar jQuery nessa aplicação, somente Angular.

```
<a href>
    <xx-chip></xx-chip>
</a>
```

Obrigado.

Comment: Seria bem tranquilo utilizar [`.is()`](http://api.jquery.com/is/), porem infelizmente não disponho deste recurso.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depois de uma analise e alguns `console.log` no codigo, consegui achar a solução que tanto estava desejando:

```
angular
    .module('xx.chip', [])
    .directive('xxChip', chip);

function chip() {
    var directive = {
        ...
    };

    return directive;

    function link(scope, element) {
        // Remove o underline do elemento pai se for um link
        if (element.parent()[0].localName === 'a') {
            element.parent().css('text-decoration', 'none');
        }
    }
}
```

Espero que ajude outros desenvolvedores.

Answer (score 0):

Eu acho que esta é a melhor resposta, vai te ajudar a resolver, é exatamente o que queres só que usando a expressão mais usual (pai e filho), como convencionalmente utilizamos (SO-eng):

HTML

```
<div ng-app ng-controller="ParentCtrl as pc">
    <div ng-controller="ChildCtrl as cc">
        <pre>{{cc.parentCities | json}}</pre>
        <pre>{{pc.cities | json}}</pre>
    </div>
</div>
JS

function ParentCtrl() {
    var vm = this;
    vm.cities = ["NY", "Amsterdam", "Barcelona"];
}

function ChildCtrl() {
    var vm = this;
    ParentCtrl.apply(vm, arguments); // Inherit parent control

    vm.parentCities = vm.cities;
}
```

Se você usar o controller como método você também pode acessar o escopo pai como se segue:

```
function ChildCtrl($scope) {
    var vm = this;
    vm.parentCities = $scope.pc.cities; //Note que PC é uma referência para o "ParentCtrl como pc"
}
```

Como você pode ver, existem muitas maneiras diferentes no acesso aos escopos '$scope'.

Fiddle:

```
function ParentCtrl() {
    var vm = this;
    vm.cities = ["NY", "Amsterdam", "Barcelona"];
}

function ChildCtrl($scope) {
    var vm = this;
    ParentCtrl.apply(vm, arguments);

    vm.parentCitiesByScope = $scope.pc.cities;
    vm.parentCities = vm.cities;
}

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.20/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app ng-controller="ParentCtrl as pc">
  <div ng-controller="ChildCtrl as cc">
    <pre>{{cc.parentCities | json}}</pre>
    <pre>{{cc.parentCitiesByScope | json }}</pre>
    <pre>{{pc.cities | json}}</pre>
  </div>
</div>
```

Original: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21453697/angularjs-access-parent-scope-from-child-controller

Comment: Provavelmente eu não soube explicar melhor, eu so preciso checar se o elemento pai é um link (a).

Comment: Rapaz, nesse caso javascript puro resolve não ?  Define um atributo name='xx-chip' para a tag 'xx-chip' <xx-chip name='chip'></xx-chip>, e depois dá um nome para <a href name='href'></a> e faz isso: var x = document.getElementById("xx-chip").parentElement.nodeName; .